# Parsing based of property type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

would you help me with some ideas?

I want to cast based on type of property, example:

```
string origincast= "2020-12-31";
DateTime fecha =ChangeType<typeof(fecha)>(origincast);
```

For this I created

```
 private static T ChangeType<T>(object o)
    {
        Type conversionType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, conversionType);
    }
```

The problem..T input does not accept typeof(fecha) as T... How can I pass the type of property as T to function?

Comment: https://tyrrrz.me/blog/return-type-inference

Comment: How is your code expected to handle type conversion errors?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you are asking here. You could invoke the Generic Method using reflection. For example,

```
var methodInfo = typeof(HelperMethods).GetMethod(nameof(HelperMethods.ChangeType)); // HelperMethods or Type where ChangeType is defined.
var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(fecha.GetType()); // or pass the Type you desire
var result = genericMethod.Invoke(this, new[]{origincast});
```

Comment: This is using reflection though, which defeats the point of using generics as it doesn't generate code guaranteed to be correct by the compiler.

Comment: @Dai I agree with you, and I liked Alexei's reference.